find -exec grep can locate results, while grep directly in the file returns nothing
Why I can find some results using find -exec grep, but when I want to search in the file itself, grep returns nothing?
[me@host logs]$ find . -iregex .*271.*.log.2024.09.26.* -exec grep "WstxIOException" {} +
./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.31:Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.31:Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
./fuse_app-271-c4fjw.log.2024.09.26.31:Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
./fuse_app-271-c4fjw.log.2024.09.26.32:Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.32:Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.32:Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
[me@host logs]$ ll ./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.31
-rw-r--r--. 1 11200 11200 209717550 Sep 26 09:24 ./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.31
[me@host logs]$ grep "Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null" ./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.31
[me@host logs]$

Version: grep (GNU grep) 2.20
Edit: I tried to search the same pattern, still no hit. With or without quotes.
[me@host logs]$ grep WstxIOException ./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.31
[me@host logs]$ grep "WstxIOException" ./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.31
[me@host logs]$ 

Another observation is, it's a very big file with long lines:
[me@host logs]$ file ./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.31
./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.31: ASCII text, with very long lines
[me@host logs]$ ll --block-size=MB ./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.31
-rw-r--r--. 1 11200 11200 210MB Sep 26 10:19 ./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.31

And there are 12319 files in the same dir, all with kind of same size. In total 2.3TB log files
[me@host logs]$ ll --block-size=MB | tail -10
-rw-r--r--. 1 11200 11200   3MB Sep 18 23:53 fuse_app-mock-66-h8ndc.log.2024.09.18
-rw-r--r--. 1 11200 11200  41MB Sep 19 23:53 fuse_app-mock-66-h8ndc.log.2024.09.19
-rw-r--r--. 1 11200 11200   5MB Sep 20 23:53 fuse_app-mock-66-h8ndc.log.2024.09.20
-rw-r--r--. 1 11200 11200   3MB Sep 21 23:53 fuse_app-mock-66-h8ndc.log.2024.09.21
-rw-r--r--. 1 11200 11200   1MB Sep 22 23:53 fuse_app-mock-66-h8ndc.log.2024.09.22
-rw-r--r--. 1 11200 11200   5MB Sep 23 23:53 fuse_app-mock-66-h8ndc.log.2024.09.23
-rw-r--r--. 1 11200 11200  13MB Sep 24 23:53 fuse_app-mock-66-h8ndc.log.2024.09.24
-rw-r--r--. 1 11200 11200 210MB Sep 24 11:21 fuse_app-mock-66-h8ndc.log.2024.09.24.1
-rw-r--r--. 1 11200 11200  29MB Sep 25 23:58 fuse_app-mock-66-h8ndc.log.2024.09.25
-rw-r--r--. 1 11200 11200 155MB Sep 26 23:59 fuse_app-mock-66-h8ndc.log.2024.09.26
[me@host logs]$ ll --block-size=MB | head -10
total 2427129MB
-rw-r--r--. 1 11200 11200   5MB Jun 28 10:23 fuse_app-163-55dkq.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 11200 11200 210MB Jun 28 10:22 fuse_app-163-55dkq.log.2024.06.28.1
-rw-r--r--. 1 11200 11200 210MB Jun 28 09:57 fuse_app-163-55dkq.log.2024.06.28.2
-rw-r--r--. 1 11200 11200 210MB Jun 28 09:33 fuse_app-163-55dkq.log.2024.06.28.3
-rw-r--r--. 1 11200 11200 210MB Jun 28 09:08 fuse_app-163-55dkq.log.2024.06.28.4
-rw-r--r--. 1 11200 11200 210MB Jun 28 08:42 fuse_app-163-55dkq.log.2024.06.28.5
-rw-r--r--. 1 11200 11200  15MB Jun 28 10:25 fuse_app-163-5p2k2.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 11200 11200 210MB Jun 28 10:23 fuse_app-163-5p2k2.log.2024.06.28.1
-rw-r--r--. 1 11200 11200 210MB Jun 28 09:57 fuse_app-163-5p2k2.log.2024.06.28.2
[me@host logs]$ ll | wc -l
12319
[me@host logs]$ du -ch
2.3T    .
2.3T    total

These files are Openshift pod logs on a GFS mount, from a JBoss EAP application, if that info helps.
Edit 2:
I download this file to local and grep in it, it really did not contains the WstxIOException word. Neither result when I grep IOException. Seems my way of using find grep is wrong?? But it found things in the beginning?
Edit 3:
I tried to quote the pattern and things start to work:
[me@host logs]$ time find . -iregex '.*271.*.log.2024.09.26.*' -exec grep "WstxIOException" {} +
./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.43:Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.43:Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
./fuse_app-271-c4fjw.log.2024.09.26.43:Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null

real    5m57.872s
user    0m38.994s
sys     0m33.863s
[me@host logs]$ echo $?
0
[me@host logs]$ grep WstxIOException ./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.43
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
[me@host logs]$ grep WstxIOException ./fuse_app-271-c4fjw.log.2024.09.26.43
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null

And when I check the files I could find the word. But I noticed the filenames are completely different from the ones I found without quotes.

Unquoted: ./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.31, ./fuse_app-271-c4fjw.log.2024.09.26.32, found the word 6 times
Quoted: ./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.43, ./fuse_app-271-c4fjw.log.2024.09.26.43, found the word only 3 times

Seems unquoted find found 2x occurrences and in wrong files.
Edit 4:
Some want to close the question with reason of "Needs focus" as I included file numbers/file size/context that they are logs; but I don't agree as I think they matter, because a simple local test does not have the same behaviour with less and smaller files.
I am doing the following: manually create 1000 small text files and compare the results of find | grep without quotes and grep; both give same results, and correct. The only thing I notice is that find | grep list results in random order; while grep order the files by name.
westerngun@mypc:~  [2024-09-30 11:08:49]
$ mkdir grep-test
westerngun@mypc:~  [2024-09-30 11:08:56]
$ cd grep-test
westerngun@mypc:~/grep-test  [2024-09-30 11:08:59]
$ for ((i=0; i<1000; i++)); do \
  file="test.log.2024.09.30.$i"
  touch "$file"
  for ((j=0; j<i; j++)); do \
    echo 'RandomException: '"$j" >> "$file"
  done
done;
westerngun@mypc:~/grep-test  [2024-09-30 11:09:07]
$ ll | wc -l
1003
westerngun@mypc:~/grep-test  [2024-09-30 11:10:11]
$ grep 777 *log*
test.log.2024.09.30.778:RandomException: 777
test.log.2024.09.30.779:RandomException: 777
test.log.2024.09.30.780:RandomException: 777
test.log.2024.09.30.781:RandomException: 777
test.log.2024.09.30.782:RandomException: 777
test.log.2024.09.30.783:RandomException: 777
test.log.2024.09.30.784:RandomException: 777
test.log.2024.09.30.785:RandomException: 777
test.log.2024.09.30.786:RandomException: 777
...
test.log.2024.09.30.997:RandomException: 777
test.log.2024.09.30.998:RandomException: 777
test.log.2024.09.30.999:RandomException: 777
westerngun@mypc:~/grep-test  [2024-09-30 11:10:19]
$ find . -iregex .*log.2024.09.30.* -exec grep 777 {} +
./test.log.2024.09.30.990:RandomException: 777
./test.log.2024.09.30.989:RandomException: 777
./test.log.2024.09.30.800:RandomException: 777
./test.log.2024.09.30.801:RandomException: 777
./test.log.2024.09.30.928:RandomException: 777
./test.log.2024.09.30.872:RandomException: 777
...
westerngun@mypc:~/grep-test  [2024-09-30 11:11:11]
$ find . -iregex .*log.2024.09.30.* -exec grep 777 {} + | wc -l
222
westerngun@mypc:~/grep-test  [2024-09-30 11:11:22]
$ grep 777 *log* | wc -l
222
westerngun@mypc:~/grep-test  [2024-09-30 11:11:29]
$ find . -iregex .*test.*.2024.09.30.* -exec grep 777 {} + | wc -l
222

EDIT 5:
Now both patterns start to work, it seems log files could be renamed and suffix moving forward? Not sure about how old log files are purged, but when I search today right now, results are correct and consistent. Anyway false alarm, we could close the question.
Sorry for the hassle and thanks for helping.
[me@host logs]$ date; find . -iregex .*271.*.log.2024.09.26.* -exec grep "WstxIOException" {} +; date
Mon Sep 30 10:14:04 UTC 2024
./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.43:Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.43:Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
./fuse_app-271-c4fjw.log.2024.09.26.43:Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
Mon Sep 30 10:18:14 UTC 2024
[me@host logs]$ date; find . -iregex ".*271.*.log.2024.09.26.*" -exec grep "WstxIOException" {} +; date
Mon Sep 30 10:18:23 UTC 2024
./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.43:Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.43:Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
./fuse_app-271-c4fjw.log.2024.09.26.43:Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
Mon Sep 30 10:22:12 UTC 2024


always put the regex (or anything containing * and ? and other "glob" caracters such as : [ab] , etc) within singlequote or doublequote, to prevent glob expansion. for exemple:  find ./ -iregex .*.txt -print will instead become find ./ -iregex .foo.txt .bar.txt .baz.txt -print and become ko, if the current directory contains those 3 files .foo.txt, .bar.txt and .baz.txt., because the shell "sees" those glob and can expand them to match those filenames. Use intead: find ./ -iregex 'regex_here_protected_by_singlequotes' -print

Do you not see those lines with just a : grep "WstxIOException" ./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.31 ? (ie, the exact regex that is used in find's grep ?)

maybe there are also some "invisible characters" on each lines: try to add :  | cat -ve to expand ascii invisible characters as "^X" (ex: ^M, etc) and it also adds a "$" at each end of lines (to help see things (spaces? etc) just before the end of line)

lastly, add /dev/null in your find ... -grep "something" {} /dev/null + to ensure that there are always at least 2 filenames seen by grep (even if for exemple only 1 file is given to it). /dev/null will never match so will not change the output of grep, but as grep sees that 2nd file it will always display the "filename:" before printing each matching line

maybe some of the "spaces" you see are non-secable spaces, or other (unicode?) whitespaces, and not regular "ascii" space.

... or even simply tab characters instead of spaces

@OlivierDulac: cat -ve expands everything except tab=^I which is one of the more likely issues here, so you want -vet -- or just -et because both e and t imply v -- or simpler yet just -A. And if find has -iregex then grep probably has -H which forces the filename more directly than the /dev/null trick. Finally, 'secable' is not a word; I think you mean no-break space aka NBSP (8859 0xA0 or U+00A0).

@OlivierDulac I tried with same pattern, still no results.

What's the output of type grep?

type grep gives me grep is aliased to \grep --color=auto'`

Do you see a difference if you run find ... -exec grep --color=auto ...?

What's the output of echo "$?" after you run grep ...?

@StéphaneChazelas I am testing searching with find grep again with quoted pattern right now, hold on. As grep does not find anything actually in the file, I suppose return code is 1

Please simplify your question by changing the find call to find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.31' -exec grep 'WstxIOException' {} + and the standalone grep command to grep 'WstxIOException' 'fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.31' and show the output of both of those identical calls to grep. Get rid of the stuff involving -iregex and multiple output files and multiple ways you've tried to call grep and how many other files there are and the output of ll as none of that matters and it's all just cluttering up the question.

I suspect if you do that you'll discover no difference between the 2 calls to grep and that something else was causing your problem.

@daveThompson: I didn't knew about -t, I agree  "grep -H" exists but always prefer to give the more portable way, and I agree about your correction (non-breaking space. Insecable is french ^^). Thank you for the 3 remarks!

Are your logs getting rotated at a very high rate?

@EdMorton please see my last edit; grep and find grep start to get my correct and same results after using the quotes. I think the way -iregex was interpreted was wrong without quotes.

@muru I would say somehow yes; but at last I think this is not very relevant as there are not a lot of occurrences of that word

If you run find . -iregex .*271.*.log.2024.09.26.* ..., the shell will indeed try to expand that regex as a glob pattern. But it doesn't seem it could be an issue here, since if your filenames don't start with a dot and contain 271., they won't match and that glob will just be left as-is, so find gets the same way as if it was quoted.

Now, you wrote that you get matches on different files with and without quotes, but is that now compared to four days ago, or something that can be repeated now? Since the files are in some log directory, and those often get writes (and log rotataion and whatever) in the background, I'd suggest taking one of the offending files, copying it somewhere else, and then having a look at it. I.e. try grep and find -exec grep against it and see what happens.

@ilkkachu yes they are rotated files, and the index suffix increases as time goes by. But old files are not erased; the deployment number 271 is the same, meaning they are the logs from the same version of the same pods in Openshift.

This question is a large pile of conflicting information. Sometimes it shows different output from the same file name for find+grep vs grep alone, other times it shows the same output. You've said in comments that once you quote the regexp for find -iregex you get consistent results but that doesn't explain what you show at the start of the question, but what you show at the start doesn't show the same results as what you show at the end anyway. I can't figure out what the real problem is you're asking for help with. If you do still have a problem please fix your question to clearly show it.

Showing output of find -iregex .*log.2024.09.30.* is pointless as that's just plain wrong syntax, you should be using find -iregex '.*log.2024.09.30.*' instead, so if your problems go away when you add the missing quotes then you don't have a problem. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes to learn about quotes.

@WesternGun, based on that last edit, it looks like you can't repeat your first experiment, since the same command now produces different output. That either means your files are changing under you, or your system is broken in some way. Neither one of those is something anyone here can really help you with. One reason I suggested moving some of the offending files to a separate location is that then you could also edit them to try to come up with smaller test material, hopefully something that could then be shared in full.

right now, we can't see what files you really have, what they really contain (or what that glob .*log.2024.09.30.* matches, in the unlikely case that you do have files it would match). Also you refused to do what Ed asked and to run find without the glob or -iregex match confusing the issue. Not much anyone can do here.

@ilkkachu I agree. The files may be moving while logs rotating, sorry for the hassle; maybe better to close the question.

You're not comparing like-for-like:

Your find command (in which you should always quote patterns and regular expressions) is looking for WstxIOException
Your direct grep is looking for Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null

You will find that if you use the same pattern match string in both situations you'll get the same result,
find . -iregex '.*271.*.log.2024.09.26.*' -exec grep 'WstxIOException' {} +
grep 'WstxIOException' ./*271*.log.2024.09.26*

The implied question is why you can't match on the larger pattern, which visually appears to be Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null. I would suggest that this is because one or more of the characters are not what you expect (e.g. tab instead of space), or there are invisible (non-printing) characters in the file.

Worth noting that the patterns are not equivalent as -iregex matches on the whole path and case insisitively and . matches any one character there, so it would match on ./foo271/LOGA2024909326/file.html for instance. For them to be closer, it would have to be -regex '.*271[^/]*\.log\.2024\.09\.26[^/]*'

@ChrisDavies I try to grep the same pattern, still not found: [me@host logs]$ grep WstxIOException ./fuse_app-271-2k2xn.log.2024.09.26.31 [me@host logs]$. Even it returns very fast.

Edit added in OP

It is weird that, with the same user and from the same directory, find can grep "something" in "./a_filename", but the user can not grep "something" "./a_filename".
I do not see, so far, any reason why both commands you tried may output different results...
Ensure that you do both in the same context (ie, both done with you loggued in with the right user, using the command-line, and not "1 in a script and the other one in a command-line" ?)
To see more precisely what filenames match: you could print the inodes of the matching files, by placing a -printf ... after the -exec grep ..+ (so it will printf only for those where the grep returns 0)
ie, try:
cd /the/right/directory
LC_ALL=C find . -iregex '.*271.*.log.2024.09.26.*' -exec grep -q "WstxIOException" {} + -printf '%i %f\n' | cat -ve
 # I added -q to the grep to not output anything, we just needs its returnCode (0 if it matches something in that file)
 # then compare to:
cd /the/right/directory
LC_ALL=C ls -i $( LC_ALL=C grep -rl "WstxIOException" ./) | cat -ve # this will match any file, not just those matching the filename regex
 # which hopefully output the same "inode_number filename"(s) as the find above 
 # with maybe many more (as it looks every files)

The LC_ALL=C is to force the locale to one we know, and the | cat -ve is to display some of the ascii "non-printable" characters as ^X (ex: ^M for LF, ^@ for NUL, etc)
